# Combine 2 queries to prevent having to insert query inside foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 queries:

1. One outside of the foreach loop.
2. One inside of the foreach loop that needs data from the first query.

Question: Is there a way to combine the 2 queries (to prevent from having to run the query inside the loop)
Or will it run fine the way it is.

**Query outside of loop**

```
"SELECT 
ads.ad_id,
ads.ad_date,
ads.ad_user,
ads.ad_approved,
ads.ad_expired,
users.user_id,
users.username,                 
users.onOffline
                    
FROM
    ads
INNER JOIN
    users
ON
    ads.ad_user = users.user_id 
WHERE 
    ads.ad_approved != '0' 
AND
    ads.ad_expired != '1'
ORDER BY 
    ad_date
DESC LIMIT $limit
";
```

**Query inside loop**

```
foreach($results as $row){

    "SELECT                                                                     
    fav_id,
    fav,
    user_fav_id                                                             
    FROM                                                                
        favorites                                                           
    WHERE
        user_fav_id = :user_id
    AND 
        fav = :ad_id
    ";

}
```

Comment: You can use `IN` clause to avoid SQL query inside a loop

Comment: I can explain with code if you provide full code in your question in php

Comment: You just need to add one more join with `favorites` table and you're good to go
`INNER JOIN favorites ON favorites.fav = ads.ad_id AND favorites.user_fav_id = users.user_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT f.fav_id, f.fav, f.user_fav_id
FROM favorites f
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM ads a INNER JOIN users u
  ON a.ad_user = u.user_id 
  WHERE a.ad_approved <> '0' AND a.ad_expired <> '1'
    AND u.user_id = f.user_fav_id AND f.fav = a.ad_id
)
```

Or, join all 3 tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.fav_id, f.fav, f.user_fav_id                                                             
FROM favorites f                                                           
INNER JOIN ads a ON f.fav = a.ad_id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = f.user_fav_id AND a.ad_user = u.user_id
WHERE a.ad_approved <> '0' AND a.ad_expired <> '1'
```

You can remove `DISTINCT` if you don't expect duplicate rows.